Can Boost (called from C++) find the exact, rational solution to system of linear equations with rational coefficients?
Does C++ Boost provide function(s) which can be used to compute the exact (i.e. rational values, not floating-point approximations) solution of a system of linear equations with rational coefficients?
I'm talking about systems consisting of, say, 3 to 6 equations and unknowns—i.e. for my purposes it doesn't have to be something that performs well for huge systems of equations.

I haven't tried, but this post mentions a templated linear solver, and there is this rational class, so you can try to combine them.

@wohlstad: That will likely be very limited. That rational class is limited to numerators and denominators “within the range of the underlying integer type.” Rational arithmetic quite easily generates large integers unless problems are specially crafted or limited in some way.

Maybe take a look at Ginac: https://www.ginac.de/tutorial/
